# How to extract current line content if it matches a condition?

Tags: vbscript

I have an input file with contents like below

> 100/17 
>   200/17

I am trying to search these values in another file and if found, I need to extract the full line where this value is found.

I tried the code below but it's not fetching current line if search found:

```
If objFile.size > 0 then
    If InStr(oFSO.OpenTextFile(strFile).ReadAll, strSearchFor) > 0 Then
        'msgbox (strSearchFor & " found in " & objFile.Name)
        strToWrite = oFSO.OpenTextFile(strFile).ReadLine
        objOutFile.Write(strToWrite & " found in " & objFile.Name & vbNewLine)
    Else
        WScript.Sleep (100)
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Please note that VB.NET and VBScript are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding how [`FileSystemObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/windows-scripting/czxefwt8%28v%3dvs.84%29) methods work. When you're opening a file you start reading at the very beginning of that file, so your `ReadLine` statement will read the first line instead of the matching line.

What you want to do is read the file line by line, compare, and then write out matching lines:

```
Set f = oFSO.OpenTextFile(strFile)
Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
    line = f.ReadLine
    If InStr(line, strSearchFor) > 0 Then
        objOutFile.WriteLine(line & " found in " & f.Name)
    End If
Loop
f.Close
```